# Hadoop counting needed terms in all splits

Tags: hadoop, parameters, sharing

I want to share some data between all the splits in the hadoop framework, more specifically, I have a file that contains alot of terms that I’m concerned to search for, and write how many times appear in each document, but the problem is that in case the word does not appear in some splits, i need to return 0 for this file, but the problem that I cant pass the terms I’m searching for to all the nodes in splits, can anybody give me some idea

Comment: Have you tried using the `DistributedCache` to share this file with terms ?

Comment: i will check, i'm still new to Hadoop, i will inform you as soon as possible(thanks)

Comment: yes, it is the solution for my problem, accept there is some modifications on Hadoop 2.X still needed to be completed.

Comment: I have posted an answer. If by modifications you mean the fact that it is deprecated, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `DistributedCache` is the way to share data across nodes. However since it is deprecated, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480460/2568511).

Comment: I'v checked this answer before, but unfortunately, this answer does not work with me, i'v got a null pointer exception.Here is my work;In the driver i have the following:\n job.addCacheFile(headers1); and in the setup i'v added the following:\n URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles(); the compilation works, but during execution i got a NullPointerException

Comment: another thinkg, i want to know where are the cache files saved in each task node ( is it in HDFS or local path) because i have found that it saves it in /tmp/hadoop-(userName)/mapred/local/(randomNumber)/, when i checkd that folder, i found it empty

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Ewiwi Ok, but to comply with the QA format of the website you should create a new question for your new problem. Also, if this answer worked for solving your initial question( how to share data accross nodes) you should mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: the new question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497968/haddop-distribytedcache-in-hadoop-2-x)