# DistributedCache in Hadoop 2.x

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

I have a problem in DistributedCache in Hadoop 2.x the new API, I found some people working around this issue, but it does not solve my problem [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480130/hadoop-2-distributedcache-deprecated-and-doesnt-work-is-there-a-replacement/20480460#20480460)

this solution does not work with me Because i got a NullPointerException when trying to retrieve the data in DistributedCache

My Configuration is as follows:

### Driver

```
    public int run(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();
        Job job= new Job(conf,"job Name");
        ...
        job.addCacheFile(new URI(arg[1]);
```

### Setup

```
    protected void setup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();
        BufferedReader dtardr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cacheFiles[0].toString()));
```

Here when it starts creating the buffered reader it throws the NullPointerException, this happenning because **context.getCacheFiles();** returns always NULL. How to solve this problem, and where is the cache files stored(HDFS, or local file system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the local JobRunner in Hadoop (non-distributed mode, as a single Java process), then no local data directory is created; the getLocalCacheFiles() or getCacheFiles() call will return an empty set of results.Can you make sure that you are running your job in a Distributed or Pseudo-Distributed mode.

Hadoop frame work will copy files set in the distributed cache to the local working directory of each task in the job.
There are copies of all cached files, placed in the local file system of each worker machine. (They will be in a subdirectory of mapred.local.dir.)

Can you refer this [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata) for understanding more about DistributedCache.

Comment: I'm using Hadoop in a non-distributed mode for testing, i will move it to fully distributed cluster, i'v read the link you sent me, but still unable to figure some points like  **mapred.local.dir**, as i understand this configuration need to be set in hadoop-conf.xml. but in hadoop 2.x there is no such file, or should i add this configuration to core-site.xml (am i right?)

Comment: Hi Mahmoud  **mapred.local.dir** property is contained in mapred-site.xml in Hadoop 1.x.This property sets the local directory where MapReduce stores intermediate data files of jobs.In hadoop 2.x the peoperty name equalent to the old one  is **mapreduce.cluster.local.dir** and it can be configured in mapred-site.xml itself.You can read about this propertie from the following link:[Hadoop Stable mapred-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

Comment: do you have a link for a working example, it seems i'm misunderstanding something, cause still got NullPointerException, but i think your solution is true

Comment: From reading this [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/yarn-dev@hadoop.apache.org/msg03094.html),I understood that if you are using Yarn then you can use the API you are using now.But if you have configured a cluster in MR1 you have to use the old Deprecated API.Can you try it in that way.

Comment: It seems i'm working around a bug (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5385) i have hadoop 2.1.0-beta I will try to change the version

Comment: yes it works fine using Hadoop 2.2.0, the problem was in the bug in version 2.1.0-beta